# Installation of GaussView on Linux Ubuntu 20.04.2 ARM

Tags: gaussian, software-assistance, apple-operating-system

Has someone made some experience with installing GaussView for Linux on an Ubuntu ARM64 virtuelle maschine? I work with an Mac M1 Chip MacBook Pro and GaussView is the only program I need to run on linux. So my idea was to set up a parallels VM for Linux Ubuntu and install GaussView on this VM.

Is there a problem with running GaussView for Linux on Ubuntu ARM 64? Or should it work?

I tried to install GaussView but it does not work. Maybe the problem is with me and not with the VM, because I try to install GaussView for the first time.

Thanks in advance for help and ideas!

Comment: I doubt there are ARM binaries for Gaussview - either for Linux or Mac. So you’d need an x86 emulator somewhere in there. You could probably run GaussView for Mac through Rosetta though.

Comment: Is it possible to run GaussView Windows Version with Mac Rosetta?

Comment: Rosetta is for running Mac x86 binaries. It won't run Windows or Linux binaries. I believe some people have used Parallels or something similar to install Windows for ARM and used the Windows x86 emulation.

Comment: I tried it with windows in parallels. But there GaussView is always crushing down and I have to restart the program. That's the reason why I tried it now with linux ubuntu ARM. I hoped it would work better

Comment: I think this is a better question for the https://apple.stackexchange.com forum - it's not really specific to modeling, more that you want to run a program. My suggestion would be to either get GaussView for Mac (which should work through Rosetta) or switch to a different program.

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but just came today to check how things are going? Did you figure out the answer? Are you still working on this? Let us know!

Comment: @NikeDattani It is not possible to install in this architectur

Comment: Did someone tell you it's impossible to install? If so, perhaps you could write an answer that says that, and a citation to the source that told you that?